# django reverse in formModel

Tags: django, reverse, modelform

In my views.py I have a class who take a (CreateView) and in the form_class take a Testform in forms.py

The problem is when in my forms.py I use the def save(...) method, it save correctly the data but the is no way to reverse after that

it say to me no matter what I try to return it says
"No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model."

ok, so I've tried everywhere to put this method but no way, it allways gives me this error

Comment: Please take a minute to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/10400050) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to redirect the user after creating a new object.

Example setup:

- CreateView is configured with url `r'^mymodel/new/', name='mymodel_create'` in urls.py.
- DetailView is configured with url `r'^mymodel/:pk/', name='mymodel_detail'` in urls.py.

You can define get_absolute_url like this:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    # field definitions...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mymodel_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Creating a new object will then redirect to the DetailView.